# Fast way to find entry in sorted map where key is the latest (lower or equals) to given number

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, find, sorting

```
import scala.collection._
val m = CustomizedSortedMap(20150401 -> "A", 20150423 -> "B")
println(m.get(20150402)) // expected "A"
println(m.get(20150422)) // expected "A"
println(m.get(20150423)) // expected "B"
println(m.get(20150424)) // expected "B"
```

How can I implement such Customized SortedMap in scala? Any example or code snippet is welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By usage of an implicit conversion from a `TreeMap` (which is a sorted map), you can easily implement such a method:

```
implicit class CustomizedSortedMap[A, +B](treeMap: TreeMap[A, B]) {
  def getLatest(a: A): Option[B] = {
    treeMap.to(a).lastOption.map(_._2)
  }
}

val m = TreeMap(20150401 -> "A", 20150423 -> "B")
println(m.getLatest(20150402)) // prints "Some(A)"
println(m.getLatest(20150422)) // prints "Some(A)"
println(m.getLatest(20150423)) // prints "Some(B)"
println(m.getLatest(20150424)) // prints "Some(B)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It works as what I expected, but I notice that "treeMap.to(a)" will generate a new TreeMap. So, there are many temp TreeMap generated if I call getLatest method frequently, does it have performance issue then?

Comment: The underlying data structure is a red-black tree, and as `TreeMap` is immutable in our case, I'm pretty sure that the `to` operations is logarithmic in complexity (so it won't copy your entire tree each time you call it), but if you have strict performance requirements, then you better measure it.